# How to handle same column headers with different values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following data:

```
S.No   Department  stock stock  stock
1       Medicine        34  38  58
2       Pharma          23  39  71
3       ortho           76  12  81
```

The source file I am getting has the repeated values of column headers as "stock", it actually should be "Stock1", "Stock2" and "Stock3".
I do not want to do it manually but programmatically.

I tried:

```py
df.rename(columns  = {df.columns[1]: 'Stock1'})
df.rename(columns  = {df.columns[2]: 'Stock2'})
df.rename(columns  = {df.columns[3]: 'Stock3'})
```

But this does not work.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several points of failure.

1. The `pandas.DataFrame.rename` method returns a copy.  You need to reassign it back to the name `df`
2. You should be doing it with one dictionary
3. That wouldn't work because you have three columns named the same thing

I have to assume some things about the general form of your problem.  First, I'll split your dataframe up into columns with `'stock'` and columns without

```
df_stock = df.filter(regex='^stock$')
df_other = df.drop('stock', axis=1)

df_stock.columns += list(map(str, range(1, df_stock.shape[1] + 1)))

df_new = df_other.join(df_stock)
```

Comment: After the split, what do you suggest should be done to achieve the result ??

Comment: df_new is the result

Comment: Actually in the second line of code ( df_other = df.drop('stock', axis=1)) , it throws an error saying: Expected Tuple, got a string

Comment: @zsh_18 I’ll have to look at it tomorrow

Comment: No worries. Many Thanks

Comment: and one more thing, if we sort the above-mentioned error out, the next error we get is- Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!.....so that the same issue of managing multiple similar header columns.

Comment: @zsh_18 I'm convinced that your dataframe is different from the one you presented.  Those differences are what is throwing the error.  I won't be able to figure out what is wrong unless you provide a sample of data that presents the problem.

Comment: @piRSqaured - No the original dataset is just larger than this one, i pasted  just a few rows for understanding. If it works for you, i am trying this again now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried df.columns=['Stock1', 'Stock2', 'Stock3']?

Comment: The reason I do not prefer doing this is, if the source file changes the first column to the last it still names the column in the same sequence. While the renaming column makes sure that where ever the position of that column is, it gets renamed right.